# Fourier transform of simple function

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis

I'm stuck on this problem

Calculate the Fourier transform of

$$
f(t) = \sin t \, , \, |t|<\pi \\
f(t) = 0 \, , \, |t|≥ \pi
$$

So the start is really simple

$$
\hat{f}(\omega) = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sin(t)e^{-i \omega t}dt = ... = \frac{1}{2i}\left[\frac{e^{-(\omega-1)it}}{-i(\omega -1)} \right]_{-\pi}^{\pi}-\frac{1}{2i}\left[\frac{e^{-(\omega+1)it}}{-i(\omega +1)} \right]_{-\pi}^{\pi}
$$
and now I am asked to simplify this so i get $\hat{f}(\omega)= 2i\frac{\sin \pi \omega}{\omega^2-1}$, I have been trying for hours and I simply can't make it! Is there anyone here that knows the trick? Maybe it have been answered before somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use this identity after you plug your bounds in the antiderivative:

$$\sin \theta = \frac{e^{i\theta}-e^{-i\theta}}{2i}$$

With this, you get

$$\frac{\sin(\pi(w-1))}{i(w-1)} -\frac{\sin(\pi(w+1))}{i(w+1)}$$

Observe

$$\frac{\sin(\pi(w-1))}{i(w-1)} -\frac{\sin(\pi(w+1))}{i(w+1)} = \frac{-\sin(\pi w)}{i(w-1)} -\frac{-\sin(\pi w)}{i(w+1)} = \frac{-\sin(\pi w)}{i(w-1)} +\frac{\sin(\pi w)}{i(w+1)}.$$

Combine denominators and you'll get exactly what you want:

$$\frac{-(w+1)\sin(\pi w) +(w-1)\sin(\pi w)}{i(w+1)(w-1)} = \frac{-2\sin(\pi w)}{i(w^2-1)} = \frac{2i\sin(\pi w)}{(w^2-1)}$$

Comment: That one I have used in the integration already, and I have tried to use it to get sine back but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: @Danny I'll Add to the answer

Comment: @Danny I hope this is clear

Comment: $\sin(\pi(w-1)) =-\sin(\pi w)$, what did you do there? I feel like I should know this haha!

Comment: @Danny $\sin(\pi w -\pi) = -\sin(\pi w)$. This is because $\sin(x+\pi) = \sin(x-\pi) = -\sin(x)$

Comment: @Danny My pleasure :)